# Optimization of loading large list of items into ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've large list(over 12000 items), that should be shown in ComboBox. ComboBox binding to list:

```
                this.cmbMCBCode.DataSource = GlobalProperties.MCBCodeList;
                this.cmbMCBCode.DisplayMember = "MCBCode";
                this.cmbMCBCode.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Binding takes much time( about 5-7 sec.), and, as it happens with every form load, it feels uncomfortable to users. I've tried to ceep filled ComboBox in memory until next form load in the following way:

```
            if ( Program.MainForm.MCBCodeComboBox.Item ==0 )
            {
                this.cmbMCBCode.DataSource = GlobalProperties.MCBCodeList;
                this.cmbMCBCode.DisplayMember = "MCBCode";
                this.cmbMCBCode.ValueMember = "Id";
                Program.MainForm.MCBCodeComboBox = this.cmbMCBCode;
            }
            else
            {
                this.cmbMCBCode = Program.MainForm.MCBCodeComboBox;
                this.cmbMCBCode.DisplayMember = "MCBCode";
                this.cmbMCBCode.ValueMember = "Id";
            }
```

But after `this.cmbMCBCode = Program.MainForm.MCBCodeComboBox`, though fields in both variables are equal, cmbMCBCode doesn't display anything on form.

Comment: try this : `Program.MainForm.MCBCodeComboBox.DataSource = this.cmbMCBCode.DataSource;`

Comment: I recommend replacing the `combobox` with something a little more user friendly, like a `textbox` with auto complete. can't you imagine your users frustration when they have to scroll through 12,000 items on a `combobox`?